# No x-default hreflang implemented (Magento 2.2.4)

Tags: magento2.2, hreflang

This is a mention from a SEO scan. Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Check my answer it will help you.

Comment: Try this module - https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-alternate-hreflang.html

Answer (score 0):

**Code sample:**

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
```

When to use Hreflang attribute:

Hreflang attribute is used in multilingual and multi-regional environments. It’s multi-lingual declaration for the site.

**Hreflang attribute is used to resolve the following issues:**

Duplication content because of targeting different markets with the same language.

Duplication content because of targeting different markets with different languages.

Targeting issues owing to targeting a country market with different languages.

Wrong specific data (e.g. prices, currency or date formats).

I have found one module to solve your issue.

Please check this [module](https://github.com/inviqa/magento2-sitemaps-hreflang)

Comment: Hi Nikunj. This is indeed for the href en but not for the href x-default